# DoWorkEventHandler "method name is expected"

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to use a method from a class that needs a parameter. I believe this is causing the error. Is there a clean way around this?

```
Clicker theClicker = new Clicker();
BackgroundWorker clickThread = new BackgroundWorker();
if (numClicks == 0 && variance == 0)
{
   clickThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(theClicker.Execute(speed));
}
```

Comment: Something like this: `clickThread.DoWork += (s, o) => { theClicker.Execute(speed); }`

Comment: that seems to be working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DoWorkEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventhandler.aspx) delegate needs `sender` and `e` arguments.

You can fix your code like this:

```
clickThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((sender, args) => theClicker.Execute(speed));
```

Note that you'll also have to call `clickThread.RunWorkerAsync();` to start the background worker going.